# Incompatible operand types String and int

Tags: java

Just a code of a bank with few functions, I am only trying to learn the way if loops are made. Seem to be getting "Incompatible operand types String and int" error on all lines that have an if,else if.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank
{
//create variables
int pac;
int confirm;
int pin;
int Bal_or_Exit;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //Receive any PAC and create if loop for continue or exit
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter your Personal Access Code (P.A.C)");
    String pac = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(pac + " is the P.A.C you have just entered.");
    System.out.println("Press 1 to continue, Press 2 to cancel");
    String confirm = in.nextLine();
if(confirm == 1)
//if loop created for confirm or exit...create another if loop for a pin of 0207
            {
            System.out.println("Please Enter your Pin");
            String pin = in.nextLine();

   if(pin == 0207)
//if loop created for pin, only access if pin=0207..access granted and 
option of viewing Account Balance or Exit               
            {
                System.out.println("Welcome!");
                System.out.println("Press 1 for Balance");
                System.out.println("Press 2 to Exit");
                String Bal_or_Exit = in.nextLine();
//if 1 is pressed, display balance of €2965.33                  
            if(Bal_or_Exit == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Your balance is €2965.33");
                }
//if 2 is pressed, display goodbye message                  
            else if(Bal_or_Exit == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("GoodBye, Have a Nice a Day!");
                }
//if anything else is pressed display error message                 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("We're Sorry, An Error has Occured"); 
                }
                }
//if pin is anything except 0207 , display wrong pin message            
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The PIN you Have entered is incorrect");
        }
        }
//if confirm = 2 (exit), display exit and goodbye message
else if(confirm == 2)
{
System.out.println("You have selected exit");
System.out.println("Have a Nice Day!");
}
//if confirm is not = 1 or 2, display error message
else
{
    System.out.println("We're Sorry, An Error has Occured");
}
}
}
```

Comment: First the first, Java **is NOT** Javascript

Comment: `if(pin == 0207)`, woah, slowly. An `int` does not have leading zeroes, it will just hold `207`. You should therefore not use an `int` to represent a PIN.

Comment: Is this homework / an assignment? I think you should consult with your instructor / fellow students / text book / tutorial.

Comment: I'm only teaching myself off the internet for 4 days so far! Don't have anyone I can ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that error due to [`Scanner#nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) returns a `String`, so, when you call:

```
String confirm = in.nextLine();
```

`confirm` is a `String` and then you're trying to compare:

```
if(confirm == 1)
```

In other words:

```
if (String == int)
```

You should either:

- Call [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())
- Change your `if` as follows:

  ```
  if (confirm.equals("1"))
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a string with an integer because they are two different data types. You will have to cast the string to an integer to do this.
Like this:

```
if(Integer.parseInt( confirm  ) == 1)
```

Alternatively you can cast the user input before storing it in the string variable.

```
int confirm = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

You can also read the user input as an integer instead of a string.

```
int confirm = in.nextInt();
```

For the value 0207 it would be more sensible to compare it as a string because of the leading 0. This information would get lost if you compare it as an integer. To compare strings you can use the equals() method.

```
if(pin.equals("0207"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code. Take `if(pin == 0207)` as an example:

- `pin` is a string so it can't be compared to a number like that
- strings need to be compared via `equals()` and not `==`
- `0207` is an *octal* literal, i.e. in decimal it would be the number 135.

To fix that change `pin == 0207` to `pin.equals( "0207" )` and the other string comparisons such as `confirm == 1` accordingly too.

You could also try to parse the strings to numbers, e.g. `Integer.parseInt( confirm) == 1` but since `0207` is probably meant to be used as it is you need to use `String` here anyways.